# AutoScroll in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have designed the following Page. The Editor which can have a length up to 1000 should be scrollable. To achieve this i added the ScrollView. This works! - I can scroll on iOS and Android when the Editor is not in "EditMode"

The Problem comes when the Keyboard is visible.

1. On Android the Editor scrolls if the text will be hidden by the Keyboard. - On iOS this is not working new lines are overlapped by the Keyboard.
2. On iOS i can scroll in the Editor when Keyboard is present, on Android this isn't possible.

   ```
   <ContentPage.Content>
   <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="*" />
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

       <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
           <Image Source="edit.png" Style="{StaticResource detailImageStyle}"/>
           <Label Text="Bemerkung bearbeiten..." VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="#be0029" />
       </StackLayout>

       <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Color="#CCCCCC" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="1" />
       <ScrollView Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="2">
       <Editor x:Name="editor"  Text="{Binding Bemerkung}">
           <Editor.Behaviors>
               <behaviors:EditorLengthValidatorBehavior MaxLength="1000" />
               <behaviors:EditorRemoveDoubleReturnsBehavior />
           </Editor.Behaviors>
       </Editor>
       </ScrollView>
   </Grid>
   ```

How do i get the scrolling work correctly? Which means:

1. Editor is automatically scrolling when Keyboard is visible and would overlap the Text
2. Editor can be scrolled on Android when Keyboard is visible

// Edit1:

If the entry is initialized with a large ammount of text the automatically scrolling effect works on iOS when Keyboard is open.

If the edit is only initialized with 1 line of text and you add a few lines so the text is overlapped by the keyboard its not scrolling.

Edit2:

I tried to remove the ScrollView and set a fixed Height to the third Grid Row (250). Now it seems to work. But its not a good Solution.
With Keyboard enabled it works and looks pretty good.

[image]

***And now with a closed Keyboard:***

[image]

Comment: "How do i get the scrolling work correctly?" - Could you specify "correctly" a bit more?

Comment: "Editor can be scrolled on Android when Keyboard is visible"-- I test on my side, the content of editor can be scrolled when the keyboard is visible.